# Automate HP ProtectTools using MDT

Tags: hp, encryption, unattended, silent, mdt-2012

Our company is currently using HP ProtectTools to perform Drive Encryption on our HP laptops. I recently built an MDT 2012 Deployment Share to automate our imaging process and would like to find a way to create an unattended or silent install of HP ProtectTools (and its Drive Encryption component) to use with MDT.

I know I can bundle it in a reference image. The problem is not every device needs it, and our different generations of laptops support different versions of ProtectTools (v. 5, 6, 7). Also, I firmly believe that a "golden master" image should only have the OS and updates, not third-party applications to manage. I have also looked into the .exe file to see if I could extract any MSI installers, but found none.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make this work?

Comment: Are you sure that the newer ProtectTools won't work with the older laptops? What did HP say about it?

Comment: I have put ProtectTools 7 onto some of the older laptops. It mostly works, though we occasionally get weird issues. Our HP rep's tech guy is mostly useless. He responded to my inquiry by sending me a PDF explaining the benefits of using ProtectTools. Either way, even silent flags for version 7 alone would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My HP rep was able to give me an answer after further prodding.

In each HP SoftPaq downloaded through SoftPaq Download Manager, there is a .cva file that contains, among other things, the silent install instructions. I haven't tested this yet, but assume it should work.

In the case of ProtectTools 7, I simply need to extract the SoftPaq files from the .exe and run the command `setup.exe /q`. Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

To Make this work on your MDT, First download HP Protect tools Cient, HP Drive Encryption (and optionally Validity Driver) extract them from the packaged installer and then import them into your MDT Applications you will need to know the silent install switches for example Client Version 7 is "`Setup.exe /q`"

do this for each version (name a containing folder for each suite you need for the different models)
in your task sequence in the state restore section, create a folder for each model name on the options tab create a condition (if any conditions are true) and use a WMI query `Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE Model LIKE "YOUR MODEL NAME HERE"`
to get the correct model name to use from a command prompt use "`WMIC CSProduct Get name`"

Within that folder create 3 application install tasks one for each of the suite components and that's it the suite will install for every deployment for that specific model repeat for each different model and et Voila!